# Why am I receiving intermittent duplicate update errors on a MERGE statement, where it shouldn't be possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
// accessedKeys is a HashSet<string>
if (accessedKeys.Count > 0)
{
    string queryFormat = @"SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @updated_resources TABLE (name varchar(512))
        INSERT INTO @updated_resources (name) VALUES ('{0}')

        MERGE resource_access WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
        USING @updated_resources AS source
        ON target.name = source.name
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET last_access = GETDATE()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (name, last_access) VALUES (source.name, GETDATE());";

    string entries = String.Join("'),('", accessedKeys.Select(s => s.Replace("'", "''")));
    string query = String.Format(queryFormat, entries);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    accessedKeys.Clear();
}
```

`resource_access` is created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE resource_access (
    name varchar(512) primary key, 
    last_access smalldatetime not null
)
```

Intermittently, I receive the following exception during execution of my statement:

```
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than 
once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A 
MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table 
multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most
one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
```

`@updated_resources.name` is populated from a list of distinct strings, and `resource_access.name` is the primary key, meaning it's also unique. I'm merging on both tables' `name` column, and neither can have a duplicate entry.

If I break on the exception, `accessedKeys.Distinct().Count` is equal to `accessedKeys.Count`. If I execute `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(name)) FROM resource_access`, it's equal to the number of rows in the table.

Why am I sometimes receiving this error?

Comment: I would attempt it with some dummy data, see if you can't narrow down where/how it's occurring. i.e. Have 'Bob' in the resource_access table and then have both 'Bob' and 'BOB' in the accessedKeys set, to confirm that this is or is not what's causing the error. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that the names are distinct with a case insensitive search? The C# you have given to look for distinct values is case sensitive. Depending upon the collation you have set in your database the MERGE will be doing its lookup case insensitive. As such if your table has name 'Bob' and your incoming data has both 'Bob' and 'BOB' you will get this error.

Try this instead:

```
accessedKeys.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Count()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: That will be because you are a human (at least I assume you are).